# Submit datefrom html form to controller

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller

I want to submit a date to my controller using html form, I tried this but doesn't work:

```
<form action="/Home/Index" method='get'>      

        <input type="date" name="Choisir une date"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        <input type="reset">
</form>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error? Did you try putting a breakpoint in your controller method to be sure whether the request is reaching upto that point or not?

Comment: No error, when I click on submit the page is refreshed and with breakpoint date = null.

Comment: What controller? Is this an ASP.NET MVC app?

Comment: Yes it's an ASP.NET MVC app. it's works now but I have an other problem, when I choose a date and click on submit I get the new data but the date return to default value (Today in my case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add **name** property to your input element as

```
<input type="date" name="date" placeholder="Choisir une date">
```

You should get the value for date param in your controller method now. The name property should match with your controller method parameter name.

Comment: It is an invalid HTML. It should be `<input type="date" name="date" placeholder="Choisir une date">`

Answer (score 0):

First of all try with post method instead of get.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="/Home/Index" method='get'>      
 <input type="date" name="ChoisirDate">
 <br/>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 <input type="reset">
</form>
```

And in controller

```
public IActionResult Index(string ChoisirDate) {
    string ChoisirDateText = ChoisirDate;
    Return View();
}
```